# When one system is connected to many other systems in a network, what are the real-time issues that occurs?

Tags: graph-algorithm

I just want to know the issues or threats which an individual can have when his/ her machine is in network. And is it possible for BFS approach to find which machine is responsible for the threat?

Comment: Repost here https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The question is to broad to be reasked. Take a look to their site and help to See how it works.

Comment: The list is potentially endless, and very dependent on the environment and what services etc are running. You could get a whole degree in information security. But then you ask about identifying the source of a specific threat...what kind of threat are you thinking of?